# Hardware datapaths for weights and operands

Tags: machine-learning, cnn, optimization, hardware

A paper, [Survey and Benchmarking of Machine Learning Accelerators](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8916327), mentions

> Conversely,
> pooling, dropout, softmax, and recurrent/skip connection
> layers are not computationally intensive since these types
> of layers stipulate datapaths for weight and data operands

What does this exactly means, `stipulate datapaths for weight and data operands`? What are this specific datapaths, how are they stipulated?

Those operations are compared to fully connected and conv layers, which might benefit more from dedicated AI accelerators,

> Overall, the most emphasis of computational capability for machine
> learning is on DNN and CNNs because they are quite computationally
> intensive [6], with the fully connected and convolutional layers being
> the most computationally intense.